# Constructing a matrix from another

Tags: list-manipulation

Here is a matrix found in the documentation:

```
mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
mat // MatrixForm
```

Is there a simple way to create a matrix say `mat1` from `mat` with non-adjacent line and/or column, or in selecting an index according to some rules as `i` odd or `j ∈ {1, 2, 5, 7, 9}`

Comment: Something like: `mat[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2, {1, 2, 5, 7, 9}]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are looking for a fairly general solution, but you make it hard to answer because you don't specify any constraints on degree of generality you are looking for. That said, here is a fairly simple and fairly general editor that can be applied to the specific kind of symbolic matrices you talk about in your question.

```
editMat[mat_, pattern_] := 
  (Map[If[MatchQ[#, pattern], #, Nothing] &, mat, {2}] /. {} -> Nothing)
```

Test matrix

```
mat = Array[Subscript[m, #1, #2] &, {5, 7}]
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: mat]

New matrix has just the odd rows.

```
editMat[mat, Subscript[m, _?OddQ, _]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: odd_rows]

New matrix has columns taken from given list.

```
editMat[mat, Subscript[m, _, j_ /; MemberQ[{1, 2, 5, 7}, j]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: columns]